# what is the kind of code that's written inside a dead lock scenario below?

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

While looking up pieces of code that can cause deadlocks using threads, I came across this piece of code :

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            while(true){
                synchronized(str1){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(10);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                    synchronized(str2){
                        System.out.println(str1 + "::"+str2);
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    };
```

After declaring and instantiating a `Thread` object, it seems inside that thread the `run` method is written with accompanying logic and the `Thread` definition ends by closing the brace with semi colon .

What is the name of such a block of code? Is this what is called as an anonymous block?

Comment: Yes its anonymous class.

Comment: It's an "anonymous class". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating the instance of abstract class or anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785922/creating-the-instance-of-abstract-class-or-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an anonymous class isntance. This code creates an instance of an anonymous class (i.e. it has no name) that extends `Thread` class and overrides its `run` method.