# Throwing HTTP Status code exception from HandlerInterceptor

Tags: java, spring, http, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to create a HandlerIntecerptor whose pre-handle has the code structure as follows

```
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, Object handler) throws Exception {

    boolean check = //do something
    if(!check)
    {
        throw new HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS); //This line gives cannot be instantiated error.
    }
    return check;
}
```

but it says class cannot be instantiated. Is there a way to throw an http code exception from inside the preHandle?

Comment: `httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.value());
return false;` could you please try ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The class `HttpStatusCodeException` is Abstract and can not be instanciated.

Form the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpStatusCodeException.html):

> public abstract class HttpStatusCodeException

Use `HttpClientErrorException` or `HttpServerErrorException`

Answer (score -1):

HttpStatusCodeException is an abstract class which means that you cannot throw it without creating an anonymous inner class and overriding the abstract method first.

Check this question for additional info [Creating the instance of abstract class or anonymous class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16785922/creating-the-instance-of-abstract-class-or-anonymous-class)