# how to solve Cannot instantiate the type HttpStatusCodeException

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
  public CommitResponse getOneCommitInfo(String commitHash) {
    CommitResponse commit = new CommitResponse();
    for (int i = 0; i < allCommitsList.size(); i++) {
      if (((CommitResponse) allCommitsList.get(i)).getHash().equals(commitHash)) {
        commit = (CommitResponse) allCommitsList.get(i);
        return commit;
      }
    }
    throw new HttpStatusCodeException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
  }
```

The exception gives `Cannot instantiate the type HttpStatusCodeException` Error, and I didn't find any related topics after searching for a while,

Comment: Which type of `HttpStatusCodeException` are you using,need to check the `import` code

Comment: for all we know, the HttpStatusCodeException you are using is an abstract class, and you're supposed to use a subclass

Comment: Assuming that you talk about `org.springframework.web.client.HttpStatusCodeException`: the class is abstract. Use one of its 2 subclasses: `HttpClientErrorException` or `HttpServerErrorException`.

Comment: I think this is the answer you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52052146/throwing-http-status-code-exception-from-handlerinterceptor

Answer (score 1):

HttpStatusCodeException is abstract class so you can not instantiate it.
Instead, use

```
throw new HttpServerErrorException();
```

or throw another exception.